# Esta xml funciona perfeitamente nos emuladores do Android studio, mas não no dispositivo físico. Peço ajuda

Tags: android-layout

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Mensagem_Principal"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="Selecione a Categoria:"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listviewCat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Categoria"

    />
```

Comment: O que exatamente está acontecendo de errado? Tem como mostrar um print da tela do dispositivo?

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde.

Talvez seja alguma configuração diferente do emulador do Android Studio pra o celular físico que você está utilizando para teste. Sugiro que verifique o SDK Tools e também se o celular está com permissão para Desenvolvedor[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, mas o aplicativo está sendo carregado, entretanto o layout não é apresentado na mesma forma dos emuladores.